# Can durood be shirk?

Tags: shirk

When I hear the Prophet's (salla Allahu alaihi wa salam) name, I say the durood but I get scared thinking I worshipped him, I don't know how to know if I worhsipped him or not. I'm scared I did shirk.

Can durood be shirk?

Comment: Why should this be a matter of shirk? Explain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. Just for others who might be reading this when you say durood you are referring to sending salawat, peace, durood on the Prophet Muhammad (Peace Be Upon Him).

So we have to understand from the Quran that ALLAH (Glory Be To HIM) that HE (Glory Be To HIM) has commanded the believers to send durood/salawat on the Prophet (Peace Be Upon Him).

**Quran**
"ALLAH and His angels send blessings on the Prophet: O you that believe! Send your blessings on him, and salute him with all respect." (Chapter 33 verse 56)

**Hadith**
The Prophet Muhammad ﷺ said: “Whoever sends blessings upon me, ALLAH will send blessings upon him tenfold”. (Sahih Muslim, 384).

So inshaaALLAH send many durood/salawat on the Prophet Muhammad (Peace Be Upon Him). Furthermore, it is good that you do not want to do shirk. But praising someone is not shirk as long as you don't elevate that creation to become a partner of, become part of, or become ALLAH / GOD (Glory Be To HIM).

ALLAH (Glory Be To HIM) Knows Best.

Have a good day!

Comment: It's not limited to elevating a being to be Allah SWT. No polytheist ever held their gods to be equal to Him SWT let alone being Him SWT.

Comment: @Afiq As Salaamu 3laykum, so by definition polytheism means "the belief in or worship of more than one god." So they are already dont have the concept of ONE (Glory Be to HIM). If you are referring to hinduism then this question was about praising the Prophet not praising partners or creating partners with ALLAH (Glory Be To HIM).

Comment: Waalaikumsalam I was only pointing out a minor shortcoming so as to prevent confusion. But yes that is correct. Though they do affirm His Absolute Lordship. To them He SWT Is The Lord (Glory Be to Him) of their false deities.

Comment: @Afiq As Salaamu 3laykum, jazakaALLAH Khairan. I will be revising my answer to have any praise that causes the creation to be elevated to be partners or become part of GOD is shirk. That way there is no more possible confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In Quran :

"Allah sends His Salat (Graces, Honours,
Blessings and Mercy) on the Prophet
(Muhammad ) and also His angels (ask
Allah to bless and forgive him)..." (V.33:56)

According to Imam Bukhari :

4797. Narrated Ka'b bin 'Ujra: It was
      said, "0 Allah's Messenger! We know how to
      greet you, but how to send Salat on you?"
      The Prophet gj said, "Say: Allhumma salli
      'ala Muhammadin wa 'ala d1i Muhammadin,
      kama sallaita 'ala d1i Ibrahima, Innaka
      Hamidun Majid. Allahumma bank 'ala
      Muhammadin wa 'ala ali Muhammadin,
      kama barakta 'ala i5li Ibrahima, Innaka
      Hamidun Majid

(Abü Al-'Aliya said, "Allah's Blessings (in
this Verse) means His Compliments to him
before the angels, and the blessings of angels
means their invocations.")

Comment: **Authentic Durood** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1nZgQqXauk

Comment: If you face any issue with Islamic problem Ask me